# Twitch.tv API Online/Offline Not Accurate

Tags: javascript

Sometimes the status is not accurate displaying online when the channel is actually offline and vice versa. And sometimes the first channel does not display correctly. Any reason why?

Code Pen: https://codepen.io/Wizikal/full/NvJpZo/

Javascript Part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var array = ["tsm_dyrus", "summit1g", "shroud", "freecodecamp", "imaqtpie", "GreekGodX", "huni", "faker", "loltyler1"];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + array[i] + '?callback=?', function(result) {
            if (result.stream === null) {
                status = 'offline';
            } else if (result.stream === undefined) {
                status = 'offline';
            } else {
                status = 'online';
            };
        });
        $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/' + array[i],
            function(twitch) {
                body = "<div class = 'row text-center " + status + "' id = 'line'><div class = 'col-md-4' id = 'image'><img src = '" + twitch.logo + "'></div><a href = 'https://www.twitch.tv/" + twitch.name + "' class = 'col-md-4' target = 'blank'><p id = 'title'>" + twitch.name + "</p></a><p class = 'col-md-4' id = 'status'>" + status + "</p></div>";
                $('#main').append(body);
            });
    }
    $('#all').on('click', function() {
        $('.offline').show();
        $('.online').show();
    })
    $('#online').on('click', function() {
        $('.offline').hide();
        $('.online').show();
    })
    $('#offline').on('click', function() {
        $('.offline').show();
        $('.online').hide();
    })
})
```

Comment: Does the api show the status correctly when your code displays it wrong? the website says that it caches the data.

Comment: If the stream is not online, the stream will be null. Like this {"stream":null,"_links":{"self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp","channel":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/freecodecamp"}} for the getJSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few problems. You are using one getJSON call to get the status, and then another to get the user info, one is going to finish before the other, ie you haven't told them to wait for the other. You also store the status in a global variable so the values will be shared between calls.

Instead you can store each request into a variable, passing each to [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) which will then resolve when both requests finish. You can then use both results in the same then() callback.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  let streamRequest = $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + array[i] + '?callback=?');
  let userRequest = $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/users/' + array[i]);
  $.when(streamRequest,userRequest)
   .then(function(statusResult,twitch){
     //when() results get stored in arrays, [data,status,jqXHR]
     statusResult = statusResult[0]; twitch = twitch[0];

     //undefined / null are both falsy so just do a single test
     var status = statusResult.stream ? 'online' : 'offline';
     $('#main').append("<div class = 'row text-center " + status + "' id = 'line'><div class = 'col-md-4' id = 'image'><img src = '" + twitch.logo + "'></div><a href = 'https://www.twitch.tv/" + twitch.name + "' class = 'col-md-4' target = 'blank'><p id = 'title'>" + twitch.name + "</p></a><p class = 'col-md-4' id = 'status'>" + status + "</p></div>");
   });
}
```